# Помогите бороться с быдлокодом

Tags: php, wordpress, html

Парни и девушки, уже какой месяц пытаюсь оживить свой сайт на wordpress. Явно вижу, что я быдлокодер еще тот. Помогите мне реализовать такую вещь которую сделал я, только более нормальным кодом( :D ):

Итак есть: 
Есть "система" регионов на сайте, выбранный регион это категория. То есть юзеру предлагается выбрать 6 категорий, и на выбранную в последствии производится редирект. Есть меню, состоящее из 4 категорий: Аренда, Продажа, Обмен, Покупка. При клике на одну из категорий, появляются подкатегории, но именно те, которые принадлежат категории на которую кликнули в меню, а также принадлежащие уже выбранному региону. То есть, в общем, чтобы представить картину вложенности категорий:

Москва

-Аренда

--На долгий срок

-Обмен

--Квартиры

Питер

-Аренда

--На короткий срок

-Покупка

--Комнаты

Надеюсь понятно.
Как сделал я:

```
<div id="menu1"> //блок меню

<div id="order-cat" class="order"> //блок первой категории
<?php 
/* Если мы в категории и категория - регион, то получаем список дочерних категорий аренды */
if(is_category() and get_query_var('cat') == '10') {
$args = array('style'=>'none','show_count'=> 1,'hide_empty'=> 0,'use_desc_for_title' => 0,'child_of'=> 30,'hierarchical'=> true,'title_li'=>'','number'=>7); 
wp_list_categories($args);
}
else if(is_category() and get_query_var('cat') == '11') {
$args = array('style'=>'none','show_count'=> 1,'hide_empty'=> 0,'use_desc_for_title' => 0,'child_of'=> 31,'hierarchical'=> true,'title_li'=>'','number'=>7); 
wp_list_categories($args); 
}
else if(is_category() and get_query_var('cat') == '34') {
$args = array('style'=>'none','show_count'=> 1,'hide_empty'=> 0,'use_desc_for_title' => 0,'child_of'=> 37,'hierarchical'=> true,'title_li'=>'','number'=>7); 
wp_list_categories($args); 
}
else if(is_category() and get_query_var('cat') == '33') {
$args = array('style'=>'none','show_count'=> 1,'hide_empty'=> 0,'use_desc_for_title' => 0,'child_of'=> 38,'hierarchical'=> true,'title_li'=>'','number'=>7); 
wp_list_categories($args); 
}
else if(is_category() and get_query_var('cat') == '15') {
$args = array('style'=>'none','show_count'=> 1,'hide_empty'=> 0,'use_desc_for_title' => 0,'child_of'=> 32,'hierarchical'=> true,'title_li'=>'','number'=>7); 
wp_list_categories($args); 
}
else if(is_category() and get_query_var('cat') == '35') {
$args = array('style'=>'none','show_count'=> 1,'hide_empty'=> 0,'use_desc_for_title' => 0,'child_of'=> 36,'hierarchical'=> true,'title_li'=>'','number'=>7); 
wp_list_categories($args); 
}
?>
</div>
<div id="order-cat" class="sell"> //блок второй категории
<?php 
/* Если мы в категории и категория - регион, то получаем список дочерних категорий продажи */
if(is_category() and get_query_var('cat') == '10') {
$args = array('style'=>'none','show_count'=> 1,'hide_empty'=> 0,'use_desc_for_title' => 0,'child_of'=> 40,'hierarchical'=> true,'title_li'=>'','number'=>7); 
wp_list_categories($args);
}
else if(is_category() and get_query_var('cat') == '11') {
$args = array('style'=>'none','show_count'=> 1,'hide_empty'=> 0,'use_desc_for_title' => 0,'child_of'=> 43,'hierarchical'=> true,'title_li'=>'','number'=>7); 
wp_list_categories($args); 
}
else if(is_category() and get_query_var('cat') == '34') {
$args = array('style'=>'none','show_count'=> 1,'hide_empty'=> 0,'use_desc_for_title' => 0,'child_of'=> 41,'hierarchical'=> true,'title_li'=>'','number'=>7); 
wp_list_categories($args); 
}
else if(is_category() and get_query_var('cat') == '33') {
$args = array('style'=>'none','show_count'=> 1,'hide_empty'=> 0,'use_desc_for_title' => 0,'child_of'=> 42,'hierarchical'=> true,'title_li'=>'','number'=>7); 
wp_list_categories($args); 
}
else if(is_category() and get_query_var('cat') == '15') {
$args = array('style'=>'none','show_count'=> 1,'hide_empty'=> 0,'use_desc_for_title' => 0,'child_of'=> 44,'hierarchical'=> true,'title_li'=>'','number'=>7); 
wp_list_categories($args); 
}
else if(is_category() and get_query_var('cat') == '35') {
$args = array('style'=>'none','show_count'=> 1,'hide_empty'=> 0,'use_desc_for_title' => 0,'child_of'=> 39,'hierarchical'=> true,'title_li'=>'','number'=>7); 
wp_list_categories($args); 
}
?>
</div>

<div id="order-cat" class="buyme"> //блок 3й категории
<?php
/* Если мы в категории и категория - регион, то получаем список дочерних категорий покупка */
if(is_category() and get_query_var('cat') == '10') {
$args = array('style'=>'none','show_count'=> 1,'hide_empty'=> 0,'use_desc_for_title' => 0,'child_of'=> 46,'hierarchical'=> true,'title_li'=>'','number'=>7); 
wp_list_categories($args);
}
else if(is_category() and get_query_var('cat') == '11') {
$args = array('style'=>'none','show_count'=> 1,'hide_empty'=> 0,'use_desc_for_title' => 0,'child_of'=> 49,'hierarchical'=> true,'title_li'=>'','number'=>7); 
wp_list_categories($args); 
}
else if(is_category() and get_query_var('cat') == '34') {
$args = array('style'=>'none','show_count'=> 1,'hide_empty'=> 0,'use_desc_for_title' => 0,'child_of'=> 47,'hierarchical'=> true,'title_li'=>'','number'=>7); 
wp_list_categories($args); 
}
else if(is_category() and get_query_var('cat') == '33') {
$args = array('style'=>'none','show_count'=> 1,'hide_empty'=> 0,'use_desc_for_title' => 0,'child_of'=> 48,'hierarchical'=> true,'title_li'=>'','number'=>7); 
wp_list_categories($args); 
}
else if(is_category() and get_query_var('cat') == '15') {
$args = array('style'=>'none','show_count'=> 1,'hide_empty'=> 0,'use_desc_for_title' => 0,'child_of'=> 50,'hierarchical'=> true,'title_li'=>'','number'=>7); 
wp_list_categories($args); 
}
else if(is_category() and get_query_var('cat') == '35') {
$args = array('style'=>'none','show_count'=> 1,'hide_empty'=> 0,'use_desc_for_title' => 0,'child_of'=> 45,'hierarchical'=> true,'title_li'=>'','number'=>7); 
wp_list_categories($args); 
}
?>
</div>
<div id="order-cat" class="changeme"> //блок 4 категории
<?php
/* Если мы в категории и категория - регион, то получаем список дочерних категорий обмена */
if(is_category() and get_query_var('cat') == '10') {
$args = array('style'=>'none','show_count'=> 1,'hide_empty'=> 0,'use_desc_for_title' => 0,'child_of'=> 52,'hierarchical'=> true,'title_li'=>'','number'=>7); 
wp_list_categories($args);
}
else if(is_category() and get_query_var('cat') == '11') {
$args = array('style'=>'none','show_count'=> 1,'hide_empty'=> 0,'use_desc_for_title' => 0,'child_of'=> 55,'hierarchical'=> true,'title_li'=>'','number'=>7); 
wp_list_categories($args); 
}
else if(is_category() and get_query_var('cat') == '34') {
$args = array('style'=>'none','show_count'=> 1,'hide_empty'=> 0,'use_desc_for_title' => 0,'child_of'=> 53,'hierarchical'=> true,'title_li'=>'','number'=>7); 
wp_list_categories($args); 
}
else if(is_category() and get_query_var('cat') == '33') {
$args = array('style'=>'none','show_count'=> 1,'hide_empty'=> 0,'use_desc_for_title' => 0,'child_of'=> 54,'hierarchical'=> true,'title_li'=>'','number'=>7); 
wp_list_categories($args); 
}
else if(is_category() and get_query_var('cat') == '15') {
$args = array('style'=>'none','show_count'=> 1,'hide_empty'=> 0,'use_desc_for_title' => 0,'child_of'=> 56,'hierarchical'=> true,'title_li'=>'','number'=>7); 
wp_list_categories($args); 
}
else if(is_category() and get_query_var('cat') == '35') {
$args = array('style'=>'none','show_count'=> 1,'hide_empty'=> 0,'use_desc_for_title' => 0,'child_of'=> 51,'hierarchical'=> true,'title_li'=>'','number'=>7); 
wp_list_categories($args); 
}
?>
</div>

</div>
```

get_query_var('cat') == '10', get_query_var('cat') == '11' и т.п - это идентификаторы категории-регионов. А в каждой переменной $args: 'child_of'=> 45, 'child_of'=> 44 и т.п - это ID дочерних рубрик, а именно аренды, продажи, покупки, обмена, которые уже в свою очередь являются подкатегориями у категорий-регионов.

Ой, я надеюсь что хоть кто-нибудь понял, что я имею ввиду :) В итоге, поможет кто-нибудь как-нибудь уменьшить код, и перестать быть былокодером :)

Comment: [можеть вам поможет ?][1]


  [1]: http://wpcar.net/demo-car-catalog/

Comment: Нет. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Упростить повторяющиеся наборы данных просто:

```
$categoryList = array(
10 => 30,
11 => 31
34 => 37
33 => 38
15 => 32
35 => 36);
```

И так заполняем как надо

```
 $cat = get_query_var('cat');
 if(is_category() and in_array( $cat , $categoryList)) {
    $args = array(
         'style'=>'none',
         'show_count'=> 1,
         'hide_empty'=> 0,
         'use_desc_for_title' => 0,
         'child_of'=> $categoryList[$cat],
         'hierarchical'=> true,
         'title_li'=>'',
         'number'=>7); 
    wp_list_categories($args);
}
```

Думаю таким образом объем текста уменьшится в разы. При той же функциональности. Я не силен в вордпресс но думаю там есть возможность как-то еще и шаблон от логики отделить, т.к. это и так запутано. Но в общих чертах вам не прийдется писать эту кучу if-ов. Которая сейчас присутсвует

Comment: Большое спасибо. То что нужно.

Comment: Не знаю, почему-то не работает...Ошибок тоже нет. Просто не выводит.

Comment: Вы бы показали, что у вас в итоге получилось т.к. не понятно как вы это использовали.

Comment: ответил ниже.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="menu1">

<div id="order-cat" class="order">
<?php 
/* Если мы в категории и категория - регион, то получаем список дочерних категорий аренды */
$cat = get_query_var('cat');
$categoryList = array(10 => 30, 11 => 31, 34 => 37, 33 => 38, 15 => 32, 35 => 36);
if(is_category() and in_array($cat, $categoryList)) {
$args = array('style'=>'none', 'show_count'=> 1, 'hide_empty'=> 0, 'use_desc_for_title' => 0, 'child_of' => $categoryList[$cat], 'hierarchical'=> true, 'title_li'=>'', 'number'=>7 ); 
wp_list_categories($args);
}
?>
</div>
<div id="order-cat" class="sell">
<?php 
/* Если мы в категории и категория - регион, то получаем список дочерних категорий продажи */
$cat = get_query_var('cat');
$categoryList = array(10 => 40, 11 => 43, 34 => 41, 33 => 42, 15 => 44, 35 => 39);
if(is_category() and in_array($cat, $categoryList)) {
$args = array('style'=>'none', 'show_count'=> 1, 'hide_empty'=> 0, 'use_desc_for_title' => 0, 'child_of' => $categoryList[$cat], 'hierarchical'=> true, 'title_li'=>'', 'number'=>7 ); 
wp_list_categories($args);
}
?>
</div>

<div id="order-cat" class="buyme">
<?php 
/* Если мы в категории и категория - регион, то получаем список дочерних категорий продажи */
$cat = get_query_var('cat');
$categoryList = array(10 => 46, 11 => 49, 34 => 47, 33 => 48, 15 => 50, 35 => 45);
if(is_category() and in_array($cat, $categoryList)) {
$args = array('style'=>'none', 'show_count'=> 1, 'hide_empty'=> 0, 'use_desc_for_title' => 0, 'child_of' => $categoryList[$cat], 'hierarchical'=> true, 'title_li'=>'', 'number'=>7 ); 
wp_list_categories($args);
}
?>
</div>
<div id="order-cat" class="changeme">
<?php 
/* Если мы в категории и категория - регион, то получаем список дочерних категорий продажи */
$cat = get_query_var('cat');
$categoryList = array(10 => 52, 11 => 55, 34 => 53, 33 => 54, 15 => 56, 35 => 51);
if(is_category() and in_array($cat, $categoryList)) {
$args = array('style'=>'none', 'show_count'=> 1, 'hide_empty'=> 0, 'use_desc_for_title' => 0, 'child_of' => $categoryList[$cat], 'hierarchical'=> true, 'title_li'=>'', 'number'=>7 ); 
wp_list_categories($args);
}
?>
</div>

</div>
```

Ошибки нет, просто ничего не выводит. Если к if добавит else и вывести текст, то выводит его. Следовательно if не проходит. Значит не работает in_array($cat, $categoryList). get_query_var('cat') как бы возвращает string, но обрамление кавычками в массиве $categoryList не помогает. Подскажете что делать?

Comment: Судя с вашего кода вы опять занимаетесь быдлокодерством.
$cat = get_query_var('cat'); хватит получить один раз в самом верху страницы. Вы говорите, что $cat возвращается:

$cat = intval(get_query_var('cat')); или так $cat = (int)get_query_var('cat'); 

В любом случаи это будет правильно. Далее т.к. писал код не проверяя я сейчас только заметил. Мы ищем в значениях массива то чего нет. Нам надо искать в ключах:

in_array($cat, array_keys($categoryList)) в принципе плохо опять переведем так:

array_key_exists($cat,$categoryList);

И у вас должно все получится.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, сейчас попробую, отпишусь.

Comment: Все отлично работает, спасибо!

Comment: я бы еще упростил. Стоит один раз проверку делать а не 4.
А массив формировать таким образом:
$categoryList = array(10 => array('order'=>30,'sell'=>40...),...);

Comment: Я не знаю как вас благодарить, спасибо еще раз)